# Как ограничить размер log файла с log.xml?

Tags: java, log4j

Есть проект в котором используется `Log4j` и лог получается просто огромный. Нужно ограничить его 5Mb если размер превышен то создается новый файл, а файлов не больше 10. Тоесть создание 11-го удаляет 1-ый. Пока удалось только создать общую схему лога в файл:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <appender name="consoleAppender" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">

        <encoder>
            <Pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5level %logger{36} - %msg %n
            </Pattern>
        </encoder>
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
            <level>TRACE</level>
        </filter>
    </appender>

    <appender name="fileAppender" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- daily rollover -->
            <FileNamePattern>log/log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</FileNamePattern>

             <!--keep 30 days' worth of history -->
            <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>

        <encoder>
            <Pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss} %-5level %logger{35} - %msg %n</Pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger name="org.codingpedia" additivity="false" encoding="UTF8">
        <level value="DEBUG" />
        <appender-ref ref="fileAppender"/>
        <appender-ref ref="consoleAppender" />
    </logger>

    <root>
        <level value="DEBUG" encoding="UTF8" />
        <appender-ref ref="consoleAppender" />
        <appender-ref ref="fileAppender"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать такой контрольнад содержимым из того что уже есть? Спасибо.

Comment: Добавьте в appender такое проперти :
 <maxFileSize>5MB</maxFileSize>

Comment: @aleshka-batman, думаю, это вполне в ответ можно написать)